# how to pass selectField value when a select is disabled

Tags: flask, wtforms

i am using flask-wtf to do something, and when a selectField is disabled, then that selectField is fail to validate because self.data is None. does anybody know why?

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}

{% if g.access_level == 0 %}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.school) }}
{% else %}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.school, disabled=True) }}
{% endif %}

{{ wtf.form_field(form.holiday_date) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.holiday_name) }}
{{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
```

if not disabled, then everything is right

Comment: That's just how select options work - if the select field is disabled, the data is not passed through.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error for a while now, as the comments said this is not an error but the default behavior. In my case, I was disabling a select using jQuery, and changing its value, when I tried to read the value from Flask I was receiving an blank list. My solution in my case was change the order.
The original:

```
$("#type").change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == 'bug') {
      $("#priority").val(5).prop('disabled',true);
    } else {
      $("#priority").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```

And the way it works for me:

```
$("#type").change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == 'bug') {
      $("#priority").prop('disabled',true).val(5);
    } else {
      $("#priority").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```

I don't know if this will be a good answer, but I hope it will be for someone.